# Cannot change the value of one pointer to temp pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

```cpp
LOAI* ba = nullptr;
LOAI* me = nullptr;
LOAI* con = nullptr;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    LOAI* x = nullptr;
    if (i == 0)      x = &ba;
    else if (i == 1) x = me;
    else if (i == 2) x = con;

    int loai;
    cin >> loai;

    if (loai == 1)      x = new A;
    else if (loai == 2) x = new B;
    else if (loai == 3) x = new AB;
    else if (loai == 4) x = new O;
}
```

When I try to change the value in those three `me`, `ba` and `con` through `x`, nothing happen.

`me`, `ba` and `con` change while input `x`.

Comment: You want `LOAI** x`...

Comment: Create a factory might help: `LOAI* ba = make_LOAI_from_stream(std::cin);` (no loop).

Comment: Your code just assigns to `x` **it doesn't change what x is pointing to**.

Comment: If you want to change an `int` using a pointer you need a pointer to an `int`. I'm sure you know this. But, just the same, If you want to change a pointer using a pointer, you need a pointer to a pointer, aka a **double pointer**.

Comment: you mean like 
```
LOAI** x = NULL;
  if (i == 0) *x = ba;
  else if (i == 1) *x = me;
  else if (i == 2) *x = con; 
```

Comment: @KhiTuKi No because `LOAI** x = NULL;` followed by `*x=ba;` is dereferencing a null pointer. Maybe you need `x = &ba;`. I'd like to be more certain but I'm finding it hard to understand what you are trying to do. But if your intent is to change the pointer `ba` then you need to make `x` point to that variable. So it would be `x = &ba;`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to factorize code with loop, but factory is clearer:

```
std::unique_ptr<LOAI> make_LOAI_from_stream(std::istream& is)
{
    int type;
    is >> type;
    switch (type) {
        case 1: return std::make_unique<A>();
        case 2: return std::make_unique<B>();
        case 3: return std::make_unique<AB>();
        case 4: return std::make_unique<O>();
        default: return nullptr;
    }
}
```

And then

```
auto ba = make_LOAI_from_stream(std::cin);
auto me = make_LOAI_from_stream(std::cin);
auto con = make_LOAI_from_stream(std::cin);
```

If you insist on loop, the code would be:

```
LOAI* ba = nullptr;
LOAI* me = nullptr;
LOAI* con = nullptr;

#if 0 // Possibly
for (LOAI** x : { &ba, &me, &con }) {
#else
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    LOAI** x = nullptr;

    if (i == 0) x = &ba;
    else if (i == 1) x = &me;
    else if (i == 2) x = &con; 
#endif
    int loai;
    std::cin >> loai;

    if (loai == 1) *x = new A;
    else if (loai == 2) *x = new B;
    else if (loai == 3) *x = new AB;
    else if (loai == 4) *x = new O;
}
```